# I've installed ubuntu 20.04, there is a delay in my mouse

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, mouse-pointer

my pc spec

- **Motherboard**: Gigabyte BS550M
- **Graphics**: Nvidia 3060
- **Ubuntu Version**: 20.04

I am using logitech mouse, it works good in windows. But recently I installed ubuntu. I am seeing a delay in my mouse pointer. Its pretty hard to work with that. I've followed several articles here but none of them seems working.

Thanks